# InterSystems Caché ODBC - max result length

Tags: c#, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I use ODBC for querying on InterSystems Caché db.

In C# I do:

```
DbCommand.CommandText = "select Class_getTablesMetaXml('globalName') As returnStr";
OdbcDataReader reader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Everything is OK, but if returnStr is longer than 16374 characters returnStr seems to be empty in C#.

According doc (http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20082/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_datatype#RSQL_datatype_longstrings) I should use `CStream%String` datatype, but I don't know how to achieve it.

My caché procedure method looks like:

```
ClassMethod getTablesMetaXml(globalName As %String) As %String [ SqlProc ]
{
    set global = "^"_globalName

    set xmlString = "<global><name>"_globalName_"</name>"

    set tableCount = 0
    set iTab = ""
    for
    {
        set tableCount = tableCount+1
        set iTab = $order( @global@("tab", iTab) )
        quit:(iTab = "")

        set xmlString = xmlString _ "<table>"
        set xmlString = xmlString _     "<title>"_@global@("tab", iTab, "Name")_"</title>"
        set xmlString = xmlString _     "<indexTab>"_iTab_"</indexTab>"

        set i=""
        set propCount = 0
        for
        {
            set propCount = propCount + 1
            set i = $order( @global@("tab",iTab,"sMeta", i) )
            quit:(i = "")

            set xmlString = xmlString _ "<col>"
            set xmlString = xmlString _     "<title>" _ ..zcvXml(@global@("tab",iTab,"sMeta",i)) _ "</title>"
            set xmlString = xmlString _     "<name>prop" _ propCount _ "</name>"
            set xmlString = xmlString _     "<format>" _ ..zcvXml($g(@global@("tab",iTab,"sMeta",i,"Format"))) _ "</format>"
            set xmlString = xmlString _ "</col>"
        }
    set xmlString = xmlString _ "</table>"
    }

    set xmlString = xmlString _ "</global>"

    q xmlString
}
```

My Caché version is: **2009.1.3 (Build 704U)**

In configuration I have checked: **Enable Long Strings**

After query `"select Class_getTablesMetaXml('globalName') As returnStr"`, I get XML string. But if its longer than 16374, I get empty string in my C# app where I use ODBC for querying. I need solve it or do something like get string of 15000 length and then second string which I will concatenate in my app(c#), but i absolutely don't know how to do it.

Comment: As I'm not a c# developer, could you add some more such code? Because I can't achieve such trouble in other languages and tools. I tried JDBC and some ODBC tools.

Comment: And which version do you use ?

Comment: I edited my question again :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get such version, and managed to try with the earliest 2012.2 version and with 2015.1 and it works well.

Comment: OK, so thanks ... It looks like something about configuration only :) .... Btw, it was suggested to me to use web services instead of sql query for solve my quest :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use CStream%String you should change return type from %String to %GlobalCharacterStream in your SqlProc and change your code because it is Stream. And for generating XML, try to use [%XML.Writer](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20091/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25XML.Writer)

Comment: Thx for %XML.Writer recommend